# Switch statements not executed inside a loop and loop not looping

Tags: c#, while-loop, switch-statement

**Problem solved! Thank you guys!!!**

Here is a question regarding C#.

I have a menu with 4 options:

1. Add words
2. Show word list
3. Play
4. Quit

I have made it with a switch and the switch is inside a while loop in order to be able to return to the meny after any of the selections has been executed.

The problem I´m having is that nothing is happening when I make a selection from the menu and I get an error message that the program stopped.. And it´s not looping...
It worked fine before I put it in the while loop. So something is not working with the switch in the while loop.

Really appreciate any help given. I´m a beginner so please try and explain easy:)

I´m pasting all my code which I have so far located in 2 files. One is called program.cs and the otherone wordlist.cs:

The program.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

class Hangman
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Title = "C# Hangman";
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome To C# Hangman!");

        //MENU
        int MenuChoice = 0;
        while (MenuChoice != 4)
        {

        Console.Write("\n\t1) Add words");
        Console.Write("\n\t2) Show list of words");
        Console.Write("\n\t3) Play");
        Console.Write("\n\t4) Quit\n\n");

        Console.Write("\n\tChoose 1-4: ");        //Choose meny item

        MenuChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        WordList showing = new WordList();

        MenuChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

        switch (MenuChoice)
        {
            case '1':               
                Console.Write("\n\tAdd a word\n\n");
                var insert = Console.ReadLine();
                showing.AddWord(insert);
                Console.Write("\n\tList of words\n\n");
                showing.ListOfWords();                
                break;
            case '2':
                Console.Write("\n\tList of words\n\n");
                showing.ListOfWords();



                break;


            case '3':   //Running game

                int guesses;
                Console.Write("\n\tHow many faults can you have: ");
                guesses = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("\n\tAwesome, let´s play!\n");


                String input;
                bool wrong;
                int NumberOfTries = 0;


                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tWrong guesses: " + NumberOfTries + " / " + guesses + "\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tGuessed letters:\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tWord:\n");
                    Console.Write("\n\n\tGuess letter: ");
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("\n\n\t ");

                    wrong = !input.Equals("t") &&
                          !input.Equals("e") &&
                          !input.Equals("s") &&
                          !input.Equals("t");
                    if (wrong)
                    {
                        NumberOfTries++;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tWrong letter " + "Try again!");
                    }
                    if (wrong && (NumberOfTries > guesses - 1))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tYou have failed " + guesses + ". End of game!\n");
                        break;
                    }

                } 
                while (wrong);
                if (!wrong)
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tWhohoo congrats!");

                break;

            case '4':
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tEnd game?\n\n");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, invalid selection");
                break;  
        }
        MenuChoice++;
        if (MenuChoice < 30)
            continue;
        else
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

WordList.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class WordList
{
    List <string> words = new List<string>();

    public void ListOfWords()
    {
        words.Add("test");         // Contains: test
        words.Add("dog");          // Contains: test, dog
        words.Insert(1, "shit"); // Contains: test, shit, dog

        words.Sort();
        foreach (string word in words) // Display for verification
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);

        }

    }

    public void AddWord(string value){
        words.Add(value);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your condition twice:

```
// This is the one you likely want, as it will read "1", "2", "3", "4", etc
MenuChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
WordList showing = new WordList();

// Remove this!  You only need to read once...
// MenuChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

In addition, your case statements are switching on characters, not numbers:

```
case 1: // Change to 1, not '1'
```

Since you're converting to an int above, you need to switch on the numerical values.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to echo a subset of your own code back at you, in an effort to explain what's going on.  Specifically, this is everything that touches `MenuChoice`, except the `switch` itself.

```
int MenuChoice = 0;
while (MenuChoice != 4)
{
    MenuChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    MenuChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

    // switch here.

    MenuChoice++;
    if (MenuChoice < 30)
        continue;
    else
        break;
    }
}
```

Now that we have this subset of code, lets step through it.

```
set MenuChoice = 0
is MenuChoice != 4? Yes, so loop.
    set MenuChoice to a number from Console
    set MenuChoice to a number from Console
    do Switch logic
    set MenuChoice to MenuChoice + 1
    is MenuChoice < 30? Yes, so go to next loop
is MenuChoice != 4? Yes, so loop.
    set MenuChoice to a number from Console
    set MenuChoice to a number from Console
    do Switch logic
    set MenuChoice to MenuChoice + 1
    is MenuChoice < 30? Yes, so go to next loop
is MenuChoice != 4? Yes, so loop.
    set MenuChoice to a number from Console
    set MenuChoice to a number from Console
    do Switch logic
    set MenuChoice to MenuChoice + 1
    is MenuChoice < 30? Yes, so go to next loop
Repeat until 3 is entered.
```

I don't know why you're incrementing `MenuChoice`, or why you're testing it against `30`, but there's no point to that code.

Answer (score 2):

In your switch loop you are getting MenuChoice and it is  integer. But in cases you are comparing it with Char. So, this is the source of exception. Change

```
case '1':
```

to

```
case 1:
```

and also others.

Also you have called Console.Readline() twice here:

```
 MenuChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 WordList showing = new WordList();

 MenuChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

You can delete the last one, because in my opinion it is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following lines of code:

```
MenuChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
switch (MenuChoice)
{
    case '1':
```

You're getting an `int`, and then you're comparing with a `char`. Use `case 1:`

Plus, why both `Console.ReadLine()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem seems to be the extra Console.ReadLine() here. Remove the second as first thing

```
 MenuChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 WordList showing = new WordList();

 MenuChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // <--- Remove this line
```

The switch case is not correct for the reason other people already mentioned (int vs string) but that's not the cause of your error. That will cause the switch always executing the `default` statement but not an error. No question that you need to fix that though.